# Getting Max Value from a changing variable

Tags: android, function, variables, listener

I'm developing an app that gets values from an Arduino in Real Time.
It gets the angle of a machine non stop.

I need my app to get the max value from all the values it received from the Arduino and when it reaches 0 degrees after the 1st movment start another function.

Or if you can, how do I call functions when that value hits a specific value?

for example, on the image, how can I make the app call another function when the pointer hits the green range.

[image]

Thnaks

I tried something like this but doesn't work.

```
if (x>y){
            y=x;
        }

test5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                x=x+5;
                Log.d("valuey", Integer.toString(y));
                Log.d("valuex", Integer.toString(x));
            }
        });
```

Comment: you should add some code, but anyway I think that calling the method only when the value is in a range must be done arduino's side, not app side. If you want to do it app-side, just create a variable where you store the value, and if the new value is higher, replace it. What have you tried?

Comment: I can't do it on the arduino side, because I need to see all the values on the app. And I need to get the max value, and after that see when the pointer returns to the green area to go to the next function. Yes i tried it but it doesn't record it.

Comment: ok, so what have you done app side? show some code pls

Comment: I added some code I used to test If I could do it:D

Comment: add some more.. btw you said it doesn't work. what do you mean? what does it do instead of saving the max value?

Comment: I always get the same y value. The x value goes up by 5 every time I click the button but never changes the value. The thing is I have this app on processing, and there when it finishes reading the code, prints all of it and then goes through the code again. that over and over again, That makes easy for updating variables and calling functions from variable values.

On android it only reads the code once, or if an event occurs, but it only reads the code inside that event

Comment: if you create a method, fired by an event, you don't want the event to run all the code outside the method, right? :) this is the concept.. an event is a method running when something appens. so your if should be inside the event listener. Elseway you can put your if in another method and call it from the onclick listener. I suggest you to go back to some basic tutorial, I always suggest [TheNewBoston's one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out another way that makes more sence in this case.

Set an SpeedChangeListener that calls the same function.

```
speedView.setOnSpeedChangeListener(new OnSpeedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpeedChange(Gauge gauge, boolean isSpeedUp, boolean isByTremble) {
                if ((i>=-1 && i < 2) || i==4 || i==7) {

                    calculo();
                    avaliacao();

                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

im going to try something like this

```
 Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (x>y){
                                    y=x;
                                }
                                test5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        x=x+5;
                                        Log.d("valor2", Integer.toString(y));
                                        Log.d("valor3", Integer.toString(x));
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
```